# How do I fight a (wild) Pokemon with mine?

Tags: pokemon-go

Whenever I see a wild Pokemon, all I get is a ball to throw or a picture to click.

What if I want to fight it with my Pokemon?  How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't fight wild Pokemon. Currently, you can only fight at Gyms and you can only collect wild Pokemon.